# Linear Algebra - Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We are given the following problem:

Suppose that $\theta\in\Bbb R$ is not an integer multiple of π. Show that the matrix

$$ A=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta\\
    \end{array}\right]
$$
does not have an eigenvector in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

I start by calculating the difference of the original matrix and the product of lambda and the identity:

$$A-\lambda I = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    \cos\theta - \lambda & -\sin\theta\\
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta -\lambda\\
    \end{array}\right]$$

We can see that the determinant is now:

$\det(A-\lambda I) = 1-2\lambda \cos\theta +\lambda^2$

because $$\cos\theta^2+\sin\theta^2 =1$$

So $\theta=2\pi n - \cos^{-1}(\frac{\lambda^2 + 1}{2\lambda})$

Is this the right approach? What do I do next?

Comment: you are looking for roots of $\text{det}(A-\lambda I)$ (you may want to review any text you're using).

Comment: solve the quadratic equation.

Comment: Please use `\sin` `\cos` and `\det` as opposed to `sin` `cos` and `det`.  It will look better that way.

Comment: The question is now, "when does the equation 
$$
1-2\lambda \cos\theta +\lambda^2 = 0
$$
have real solutions? (for $\lambda$)".

Comment: Solve for $\lambda$, not for $\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you have can be solved using just the quadratic formula.

Solve $\lambda$ in $1-2\lambda\cos(\theta) + \lambda^2 = 0$ with:

$$\frac{2\cos(\theta) \pm 2\sqrt{\cos^2(\theta)-1}}{2} = \cos(\theta) \pm i\sin(\theta)$$

This is Euler's formula, which is equal to $e^{\pm i\theta}$, and always has a modulus of $1$.

Comment: This is a fine answer.  I just hope OP also realizes that the result is geometrically obvious, since the linear transformation is just rotation by $\theta$.

Comment: I agree. Even though these are the eigenvalues, it is more important to note that they both have a modulus of $1$, implying that a rotation will never have any scaling effect.